# Put Call Parity confusion

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics

My question concerns an ambiguity in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Put%E2%80%93call_parity) about Put Call Parity.
 In the first sentence:
 "In financial mathematics, put–call parity defines a relationship between the price of a European call option and European put option, both with the identical strike price and expiry, namely that a portfolio of a long call option and a short put option is equivalent to (and hence has the same value as) a single forward contract at this strike price and expiry."
is about a "short" put option which means that we have the obligation to sell the put but in the derivation a long put is used, i.e. a put with payoff profile $(K - S_T, 0)^+$. But a short put would be actually $K-S_T \in \mathbb{R}$ if the option gets exercised.
Edit:
My question concerns the definition of "short put". In http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/short-put.asp
it is definied as the obligation to sell and then its not the payoff: $-(K-S_T)^+$?

Comment: You don't "have the obligation to sell the put", you have already sold it so  now your payoff is the negative of the payoff of a put.

Answer (score 2):

Being short a put simply means that you have sold the put, hence its payoff is from your point of view $-(K - S_T)^+$. When your are long a call and short a put your total payoff is $(S_T - K)^+ -(K - S_T)^+ = S_T - K$, hence the call/put parity.